# Points in wrong polygon?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I have 2 shapefiles; 1 is a point shapefile with civic addresses that have community in the attribute table and 1 is a polygon shapefile for the communities. How do I determine if a point is in the wrong community polygon?

Comment: Why bother comparing the two and seeing if they're wrong?   Erase what you have in that field, or add another field, then do a spatial join.

Comment: If it were that easy I would have done that, but for the project I am working on it is not possible. I need to know if a point spatially falls within the wrong community so I can either fix the point or the community.

Comment: select by location, then highlight the points that don't match up?  No idea how many communities you have, if it's only a few, then this would be fine.  If you have a bunch, it would be better to come up with a script

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 4):

Conduct a spatial join on the two layers. Review the attribute table of the spatial join and you will be able to see where the communities don't match up. You can take it a step farther and run a select query so that a .shp can be generated with only the points that are mislabeled.

Comment: The attributes will all match up, I want to know if a point with community A spatially falls in community A or if it is within community B. If i have a list of points that are spatially in the wrong communities then I can do a review to see if the point needs to be moved or if the polygon for the community needs to be changed.

Comment: @ChandlerKane that's exactly what Kingfisher is saying.  A spatial join will join the points and polygons and then you can compare the attributes of spatially matched features (points within the polygons) and where the attributes don't match then the point is in the wrong polygon.

Comment: You could also use either the Identity tool or the Intersect tool, both in the analysis toolbox. The output from all 3 tools would look about the same though. We're assuming that there is an attribute with the community name in both the points and polygons.